# How to umount permanently /home

Tags: mount, home

To install Linux Mint, I used two partitions: `/dev/sda4` for `/` and `/dev/sda5` the other contains `/home`. However, the contents of `/media/elvis/Home/elvis` and `/home/elvis` are not the same. So, I don't want to mount `/home` to the partition `/dev/sda5` anymore and use this partition with other purpose.

I have tried using `umount` but it only detaches the partition at all without removing `/home` permanently. I thought to format it using `gparted`, but it is an unwanted solution. Which solutions do you suggest me to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of `/home`? I suppose you know that if the home directory of the user isn't available, the user can't log in... What is this `/media/elvis/home/elvis` business?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check `/etc/fstab` file: if there is a corresponding entry in there for automounting, you can comment it out by putting `#` in the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

So if you don't want `/home` on `/dev/sda5` anymore, where do you want its contents to be?

If you want to *migrate* the contents of home from `/dev/sda5` to `/dev/sda4`, you can do so with (as root):

```
umount /home
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
cp -va /mnt/* /home
umount /mnt
```

With this, you have copied the contents of `/dev/sda5` (= the old home) to `/home` (now on `/dev/sda4`, the root filesystem).